# Coldfusion: RMI Channel with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl, coldfusion

For my Flex <--> ColdFusion-App, I want to switch to SSL. Within the ColdFusion Administrator, I have the following option:

```
Lets you use Secure Socket Layer (SSL) encryption for the RMI communication
between Flex and ColdFusion. This is not required unless you are transmitting
authentication information or confidential data between Flex and ColdFusion
over an unsecured network. 
You must provide a keystore file and keystore password. For instructions on
how to create a keystore file, see the online Help.
```

The online help doesn't help me. I have already created the certs with openssl and without a password. Would I need to recreate the certificate and use a password for the CSR? Will I have any problems with apache then (if the certificate needs a password?)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer to your question, but if you don't get an answer here you might try the cf-talk mailing list at houseoffusion.com.  There are some pretty smart folks on that list who would probably be able to answer this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution.

As I create the certificates with openssl, i have to convert them to DER-format:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -inform PEM -out cert.der -outform DER
```

Then I use this great small java app for creating the keystore and passwort: http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html